# How to sum a range of calculations

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I thought I'd find an answer here for this already but couldn't find one that matches this use case.

I have two columns (in this example "cost/hour" and "hours").

```
  |      A      |   B   |
1 | cost / hour | hours |
  | ----------- | ----- |
2 | 12          | 40    |
3 | 21          | 32    |
```

When summing the data in column `B` I'd like to perform a calculation for each row, along these lines: `SUM(A2 * B2: A3 * C3)`. Obviously, this doesn't work but it hopefully describes what I'm trying to achieve. Apart from creating a new column `C` that contains the calculation result of `x1 * x2` and summing that column, is there a way I can achieve this?

*This example is hugely oversimplified from my real use case, creating multiple columns just isn't an option with the number of calculations I need to perform.*

Answer (score 0):

So I think what I was looking for was `SUMPRODUCT` that will result in the product of two (or more) arrays.

`SUMPRODUCT(A2:A3, B2: B3)` is `(12 * 40) + (21 * 32)` resulting in `1152`.